# UserManager.FindAsync always returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following Login action on a and the UserManager.FindAsync always returns null. I am trying to seed the users with the code shown at the bottom.

Can anyone help please?

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have the following bit of code for in the Configuration.cs under Migrations. What it does is seed a user that I am trying to log in with the code above.

```
    protected override void Seed(Temps.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Consultant"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Consultant" };

            manager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Consultant"))
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "Consultant",
                Email = "consultant@temps-ltd.co.uk"
            };

            manager.Create(user, "password");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Consultant");
        }
```

---

*UPDATE*

After implementing Anthony's changes I get the following error for the seed code below, any ideas?

```
PM> Update-database
  Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
  No pending explicit migrations.
  Running Seed method.
  System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.
     at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager2.<AddToRoleAsync>d__83.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func1 func)
     at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.AddToRole[TUser,TKey](UserManager2 manager, TKey userId, String role)
     at Temps.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) in c:\Work\@wandc\Temps\trunk\src\Temps\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 67
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
     at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
     at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
  UserId not found.
```

Code:

```
        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin@temps-ltd.co.uk"))
        {
            string emailAddress = "admin@temps-ltd.co.uk";

            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = emailAddress,
                Email = emailAddress,
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                PasswordHint = password
            };

            manager.Create(user, password);                
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

`FindAsync()` takes the username as the first parameter. So you would actually need change the login form/viewmodel to take a username instead of an email.

The standard ASP.NET template sets the username to the email, that's why `FindAsync()` works with an email address out of the box. So another option is to do the same thing and use the email as the username when seeding the database.

Comment: Thanks Anthony implement the change and now I get the error above?

Comment: Check the return value of `manager.Create(user, password)` for success before adding to the role. My guess is something went wrong with the user creation, probably password not strong enough. (also, nice password hint :).

Comment: :) Only using this for testing initially everything will be dropped and loaded again in live environment (I hope)

Answer (score 4):

The above answer helped me build this one.

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IOwinContext context = Request.GetOwinContext();

            

            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            var u = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            bool passhash = false;
            if (u != null)
            {
                passhash = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(u, model.Password);
            }
            //ApplicationUser user = await repo.FindUser(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else if (u != null && passhash)
            {
                await SignInAsync(u, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
```

Now you can login with username and password